# Where can I download JNLP.jar?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

How can I run the examples in [the link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html)?

Where can I get the JNLP developer pack?

Comment: Note: the Java Tutorial has a lot of examples run through JNLP and can be downloaded, if you want even more.  Remember to check that the JNLP file is correct XML.

Comment: Those examples are not as good as [these examples](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).  I can say that because the latter examples 1) Were written by me. (I might be biased) 2) Are self contained (source, JNLP and build file) 3) Have been used as 'test cases' for the JNLP API in several bug reports.  (E.G. 'The example doesn't work, so the API must be broken.').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\sample\jnlp\servlet
```

In other words, in the `sample\jnlp\servlet` directory of your JDK.

Comment: thanks bozho. I'am struggling with jdk 1.7 and it is not there. Now i took from 1.6.

Comment: The sample folder is in the "Java SE Development Kit <version> Demos and Samples Downloads" file, a separate download from the JDK. The 7u21 version does have sample/jnlp/servlet with jnlp.jar.

Answer (score 4):

You can also find the `javax.jnlp.*` classes in `lib/javaws.jar` under your JRE installation.

Answer (score 2):

The classes shown at the link are primarily of the JNLP API.  It is automatically on the run-time class-path of apps launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

As to how to add them to the compile-time class-path, see the tips in (the build files of) [these demos](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to get [there](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7664-jaws_dev_pack-1.2-demo-oth-JPR). The JAR tar balls, such as jnlp-servlet.jar, are located in lib.

Comment: What is "lib"? Is it literal?

Answer (score 0):

You find the [JNLP developers pack here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/download-jnlp.html).

Comment: here is no longer a separate JNLP Developer's Pack for Java Web Start versions 1.5.0 and beyond.

The jardiff tool, jnlp-servlet.jar file, and jnlp.jar file can be found in the samples directory of the JDK.

Comment: It comes with the JDK since 1.5

Comment: @stacker that is no longer available there..!