# Is the <jnlp codebase="..." > parameter required?

Tags: java, deployment, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a working webstart deployment of an application.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388360/java-how-to-get-ip-address-automaticallly-in-jnlp-file) says I can omit the codebase parameter.  [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/codebase_determination.html) says the codebase parameter is optional.

When I omit the codebase parameter or use

```
codebase=""
```

my web start application fails to start because it is looking for the executable .jar file in the directory where the .jnlp file is downloaded to.

I would like to omit the codebase parameter because this particular webstart application will be deployed onto several different servers and I don't want to have to customize the .jnlp file for each server.

What is the correct story with the jnlp codebase parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That post is incorrect.  The only JNLP for which it is valid to leave out the document base, are those which are used to deploy an **embedded applet**.  In that case, the code base will default to the same directory that contains the HTML.

*Launch files for frames or free floating applets need a codebase.*

---

`codebase=""`

By the way, that is an attribute with empty value, not an omitted attribute/value pair.  For the embedded applet mentioned above, you would not include that at all.

Comment: codebase is optional with recent specs of jnlp (7.0+ definitely, not sure about 6.0)

Answer (score 0):

As of Java SE 7, from the specs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/deployingWithoutCodebase.html):

> Beginning in the Java SE 7 release, you do not have to specify an
> absolute path for the codebase attribute in the Java Web Start
> application's Java Network Launch Protocol (JNLP) file. You can
> develop and test your applications in different environments without
> having to modify the path in the codebase attribute. If no codebase is
> specified, the Java Web Start software assumes that the codebase is
> relative to the web page from which the Java Web Start application is
> launched.

***If no codebase is specified, the Java Web Start software assumes that the codebase is relative to the web page from which the Java Web Start application is launched.***