# Can't find jnlp.jar in JDK 1.7

Tags: java, jar, jnlp, java-web-start

I have JDK 1.7 installed and I need to make a Java Web Start application. I searched the internet and found that you need the jnlp.jar in your project build path.

There is a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593029/where-can-i-download-jnlp-jar) where a user said it's in the jdk folder, specifically in 
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\sample\jnlp\servlet.

But that is for JDK 1.6. In 1.7 there is no sample folder and I can't find any jnlp.jar with windows search.

If there is another way to use JNLP API please tell me.

Comment: What is the technical reason you need the jnlp.jar?

Comment: To compile an application using the Java Web Start API I guess.

Comment: Actually it's for using the JNLP API in my application (open files in local storage, open new pages, etc)

Comment: Be careful, most of the JNLP services are not available outside a Java Web Start context. For opening a page you can use the `java.awt.Desktop` class introduced in Java 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it's `javaws.jar`, you'll find it in the `jre/lib` directory.

Comment: So there should be no special action on the OP's side?

Comment: He just has to add it to the classpath at compile time, it's not automatically available unlike `rt.jar`