# Where to find jnlp.jar for Java 7

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

We're trying to upgrade our app from Java 5 to Java 7, but can't find jnlp.jar in the JDK 7 installation.

In the Java 5 installation (unix machine), it was located in `$JAVA_HOME/sample/jnlp/servlet/jnlp.jar` (and also in JDK 6), but that location doesn't exist in my JDK 7 installation, and a `find` command turns up nothing.

**NOTE:** The JDK version on the unix machine is 1.7.0_11 (this is older version of 7 just temporary until a newer one gets installed). On my PC, I have 1.7.0_40, which also doesn't have the `jnlp.jar`.

According to the [JNLP API Examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html), it says that the `jnlp.jar` is included in the `JNLP Developers Pack`. Ummm, okay.

I can't find it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html

This link is dead: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/download-jnlp.html

This link looked promising, but no download for Java 7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/developers-140165.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find the jnlp api jar in jdk 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555066/where-can-i-find-the-jnlp-api-jar-in-jdk-7)

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh Thank you.  I used google, which gave me hits on SO, but not that one. Also, it wasn't a "suggested" dupe when I typed in the title.  Thanks again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find jnlp.jar in JDK 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830317/cant-find-jnlp-jar-in-jdk-1-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's `javaws.jar`, you'll find it in the `jre/lib` directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830317/cant-find-jnlp-jar-in-jdk-1-7/10830364#10830364

Answer (score 1):

Download the [jdk samples for windows](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18-demos/jdk-7u45-windows-x64-demos.zip). They have the jnlp.jar, jardiff.jar etc.